# Cropping an image after detecting the contours using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing

I'm trying to crop an image after detecting the contours and then extract information from it using python, opencv, and numpy.

Detecting the contours was successful but then I couldn't find a way to crop. I tried some code but I didn't get the result that I wanted:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('2.jpg') # Read in your image
blurred=cv2.blur(image,(23,51))#blur the image
gray=cv2.cvtColor(blurred,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)#gray scale
ret,threshold=cv2.threshold(gray , 2 , 255 , cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
contours,hierachy=cv2.findContours(threshold,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)#detect contours
mask = np.zeros_like(image) # Create mask where white is what we want, black otherwise
cv2.drawContours(mask,  contours,  0,  (0 ,0,255),1)
out = np.zeros_like(image) # Extract out the object and place into output image
out[mask == 255] = image[mask == 255]

# Now crop
mask=mask.transpose(2,0,1).reshape(-1,mask.shape[1])
(x, y) = np.where(mask == 255)
(topx, topy) = (np.min(x), np.min(y))
(bottomx, bottomy) = (np.max(x), np.max(y))
topx=topx
topy=topy
bottomx=bottomx
bottomy=bottomy
out = out[topx:bottomx,topy:bottomy]
print(out)
```

[image: enter image here]

The array `out` is  empty which is weird because when I print `topx`, `topy`, `bottomx`, and `bottomy`, I get integers, so logically cropping would give me a result.

Comment: @bechirjamoussi you have a tool in the text editor of SO to put your text as code. Text with a tabulation before each line will be formatted as code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to crop an image in OpenCV using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589517/how-to-crop-an-image-in-opencv-using-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, if you have the contours detected, you can crop the contours by adding the following lines to your code, just after `contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`:

```
i = 0
for c in contours:
    # get the bounding rect
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    # to save the images
    cv2.imwrite('img_{}.jpg'.format(i), image[y:y+h,x:x+w])
    i += 1
```

Comment: Welcome Bech :p

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
x, y = [], []

for contour_line in contours:
    for contour in contour_line:
        x.append(contour[0][0])
        y.append(contour[0][1])

x1, x2, y1, y2 = min(x), max(x), min(y), max(y)

cropped = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]
```

Source: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41069831/opencv-python-crop-image-using-numpy-array?rq=1#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41069831/opencv-python-crop-image-using-numpy-array?rq=1#_=_)